# Sql Command to sort data as it is stored

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select DISTINCT Month, Code 
from SalaryRecord 
order by Code ASC
```

The result is

```
Feb
Jan
Jan
```

but I want `Jan` and `Feb` arranged by month ascending order

Comment: itz as a varchar And Code is the employee-Code; and i want it to arrange month wise. and i don't have month as a number , and month is repeating again and again i also i have primary key in this table called SalaryCode

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `Month` column is a string type (`VARCHAR(n)`), so it's being ordered as a string - and the ordering is perfectly correct (`F` comes before `J` in Western European alphabets) in that case.

Do you have the month as a **number** in your table, too?

If so, you could order by that numerical value instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Month, Code 
FROM 
    dbo.SalaryRecord 
ORDER BY 
    NumericalMonth, Code ASC
```

Or maybe you have a **`DATE`** (or `DATETIME`, `DATETIME2` column?) and you could order by that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Month, Code 
FROM 
    dbo.SalaryRecord 
ORDER BY 
    MONTH(YourDateColumn), Code ASC
```

And if you have nothing at all your can easily sort on - well, then you'll need this big ugly `CASE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Month, Code 
FROM 
    dbo.SalaryRecord 
ORDER BY 
CASE MONTH 
  WHEN 'Jan' THEN 1
  WHEN 'Feb' THEN 2
  WHEN 'Mar' THEN 3
  WHEN 'Apr' THEN 4
  WHEN 'May' THEN 5
  WHEN 'Jun' THEN 6
  WHEN 'Jul' THEN 7
  WHEN 'Aug' THEN 8
  WHEN 'Sep' THEN 9
  WHEN 'Oct' THEN 10
  WHEN 'Nov' THEN 11
  WHEN 'Dec' THEN 12
  ELSE 999
   END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
select DISTINCT Month, Code
from SalaryRecord
order by DATEPART(mm,CAST([Month]+ ' 1900' AS DATETIME)) asc
```